# Android resizable window

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

Stackoverflow community!

I want to open any other Android application in resizable window(Android 10).
I try use this, but app opens in full screen window(not resizable).

```
Intent intent = Android.App.Application.Context.PackageManager.GetLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.LaunchAdjacent | ActivityFlags.NewTask);
Android.App.Application.Context.StartActivity(intent);
```

This code not worked correctly.
Please help me resolve this issue.

Thank you!
Best wishes!

Comment: It seems that you should define a `Layout` in your activity,and open the `Overview screen` and performs a long press on the activity title .You could refer to [Multi-Window Support](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/multi-window).

Comment: As per the document i linked, "If your app targets Android 7.0 (API level 24) or higher, you can configure how your app handles multi-window display. For example, you can specify your activity's minimum allowable dimensions. You can also disable multi-window display for your app, ensuring that the system only shows your app in full-screen mode." So you should make sure the appllication which you want to open had enable the multi-window.

Comment: How I can open other android app in window resizable mode for Example Google Chrome?

Comment: You should make sure the app had enable the multi-window first.